# Meaning of ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named os?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-calculator, error-000539

In Raster Calculator using:

```
(FocalSt_meanDEMtif5-FocalSt_minDEMtif1) / (FocalSt_maxDEMtif2-FocalSt_minDEMtif1)
```

What is the meaning of

> ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() : No module named os

Comment: I believe @PolyGeo has provided the correct answer. It's worth noting that when you arrive at an error message such as this, the answer can often be found by simply searching "arcgis error 000539" in your fave search engine.

Comment: There are a number of previous occurrences reported on this site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5berror-000539%5d%20rcexec Were you trying to use the Raster Calculator in Python?

Answer (score 2):

This error is discussed in an Esri Technical Article entitled [Error:  ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec()](http://support.esri.com/ja/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41859) which says:

> This error is due to Raster Calculator not being exposed to Python as
>   a tool. Currently, Raster Calculator is only exposed as a
>   geoprocessing tool in ArcGIS or in ModelBuilder. However, there are a
>   number of different ways to use Raster Calculator functions in Python.